# How to change name of the http request in chrome? (using node)

Tags: google-chrome, http

Is there a way to change the name(nombre) of the http request in chrome?
The names that are currently showing are the parameters that I send to the get request.
I'm using Node and angular

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the 'Use large request rows' checkbox in the main screen of Chrome DevTools to display the rest of each URL underneath the final segment that is shown by default

[image]